# Bing Maps Transaction Tracking

Tags: mapping, bing-maps, virtual-earth, bing

I have an Enterprise license for Bing Maps which enables me to view my transactions, but what I'd like to be able to is also break the transactions down by user. I'd like to know if certain customers are racking up higher than expected transactions.

It's my understanding that the Bing API will allow me to track by client IP, but that doesn't tell me too much. I'd like to track by user account. Possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to figure this out here's what I've found:

I spoke with my Bing account mgr and he indicated that there is not really a good way to do this. What he suggested was created separate sub-accounts with different client ids. I would then have to contact the rep and have him enable those accounts on the Production server.
Now obviously this doesn't scale well. So instead of tracking each user individually I'm going to set up a Bing account for some of our major customers and assign all of that customers users to the Bing account. 
So I won't be able to track all of my customers, nor will be able to granularly track users within the customers that I am tracking.